# While doesn't break with a an input string

Tags: python

How can I break the `while` with a string input? I was trying this, but the first if is ignored:

```
from itertools import cycle;
ewe=cycle([0]);
Nom_join="";
Principal_loop=True;
Cont_Error1=0;
while(Principal_loop==True):

    for i in ewe:
        Nom_join=input("give me a name to search: -> ");
        if (Nom_join==""):
            print("you cant do that");
            Cont_Error1+=1;
        elif(Nom_join==" "):
            print("you cant do that");
            Cont_Error1+=1;
        elif(Nom_join.isdigit()):
            print("you cant do that")
            Cont_Error1+=1;
        elif(Nom_join=="*"):
            Principal_loop=False;
        else:
            break;
```

Comment: Please remove the semicolons, they hurt every Python developer's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `break` statement after `Principal_loop=False`. And yes, please remove semicolons and add spaces before and after operators to conform with [PEP 8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations). Also, no parentheses after conditional statements.

```
from itertools import cycle
ewe = cycle([0])
Nom_join = ""
Principal_loop = True
Cont_Error1 = 0

while Principal_loop == True:
    for i in ewe:
        Nom_join = input("give me a name to search: -> ")
        if Nom_join == "":
            print("you cant do that")
            Cont_Error1 += 1;
        elif Nom_join == " ":
            print("you cant do that")
            Cont_Error1 += 1
        elif Nom_join.isdigit():
            print("you cant do that")
            Cont_Error1 += 1
        elif Nom_join == "*":
            Principal_loop = False
            break
        else:
            break
```

I'm really not sure why you need to initiate a cycle of infinite zeros... There's also a lot of other simplifications that can be made. It seems far simpler to do this:

```
Cont_Error1 = 0
while True:
    Nom_join = input("give me a name to search: -> ")
    if Nom_join in {"", " ", "*"} or Nom_join.isdigit():
        print("you can't do that")
        Cont_Error1 += 1;
    else:
        break
```